# Create log file for errors in react

Tags: reactjs

I need to create a file to log errors using react, I was checking some libraries, but those libraries just logs errors in the UI, the thing that I need is create a new file each day, each file will be named with the current date, and it should log all the errors in the day.
I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: Since you mentioned libraries, try [Sentry.io](http://sentry.io).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't log directly to the file system using front-end javascript, instead you could post your logs to a backend server & that inforth will log the message on a file for you.